# Doctrine2 reinitializes a related entity (one to one) when saving a main entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The context is a Symfony2 project (2.0.23) using Doctrine2.

I have a Candidate entity with one to one relation `Website`. When creating a new candidate I set the `Website` entity like this:

**Candidate.php**:

```
<?php

use MyProject\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Website;

public function initialize(Website $website)
{
    $this->setWebsite($website);
```

The one to one relation is declared like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * @var Website $website
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Website")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Website", referencedColumnName="Code")
 */
private $website;
```

Everything works fine locally. But on out testing and production servers, when creating a new candidate with a given Website, sometimes the associated entity is updated with default values just when persisting and flushing the main `Candidate` entity, here is the MySQL log:

```
/*!*/;
# at 11400207
#130628  9:26:32 server id 1  end_log_pos 11400399  Query   thread_id=53611133  exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1372404392/*!*/;
UPDATE website SET Name = NULL, bEnabled = NULL ... WHERE Id = 2 AND Code = 2000
```

I persist with the method of the FOSUserBundle:

```
<?php

/**
 * Updates a user.
 *
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @param Boolean       $andFlush Whether to flush the changes (default true)
 */
public function updateUser(UserInterface $user, $andFlush = true)
{
    $this->updateCanonicalFields($user);
    $this->updatePassword($user);

    $this->em->persist($user);
    if ($andFlush) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why. What is really weird is that only happens sometimes and it is quiet unpredictable.

Any suggestion or hint would be welcome... Thanks.

PS: The doctrine metadata cache was deactivated.

**Edit1**: Added persist, note that this is called through a FormHandler service.

Comment: Are you sure that you always persist $website object befor flushing?

Comment: how do you persist your entity?

Comment: @Hast: The website does not have to be updated, it is just attached to the `Candidate` entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems it was related to the main entity that had 2 `@ORM\Id` annotations. As it is an old database, it is not "Doctrine" friendly. There is a PK an auto-increment field, but the joins are made on a second column. So I removed the `@ORM\Id` annotation for the PK field.